# Set captured image from camera to ImageButton background

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm taking a photo from the camera and want to set it as a background for my ImageButton background.

Taking photo, present it in ImageView and save it to the device as well as the complete path works great.

If it's matter, here is my handling code in OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // Handling the photo

    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    if (requestCode == TAKE_A_PHOTO) {
        // Check if the result includes a thumbnail Bitmap
        if (data != null) {
            if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
                Bitmap thumbnail=data.getParcelableExtra("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        } else {
            // If there is no thumbnail image data, the image
            // will have been stored in the target output URI.
            // Resize the full image to fit in out image view.
            int width = imageView.getWidth();
            int height = imageView.getHeight();
            BitmapFactory.Options factoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            factoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true; BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputFileUri.getPath(),
                    factoryOptions);
            int imageWidth = factoryOptions.outWidth; int imageHeight = factoryOptions.outHeight;
            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            int scaleFactor = Math.min(imageWidth/width, imageHeight/height);
            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
            factoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false; factoryOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor; factoryOptions.inPurgeable = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputFileUri.getPath(),
                    factoryOptions);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to "+ incomePhotoURL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == LOAD_AN_IMAGE) {
        Uri selectedImageUri=data.getData();
        isAudioRecordPath=idanUtils.getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri, AddIncome.this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image loaded from "+incomePhotoURL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i(ItemsDataBase.TAG, "Image loaded from "+incomePhotoURL);
    }
}
```

Comment: see [THIS TUTO](http://developer-android.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-capture-image-using-camera-and-save-to-sdcard-and-display-in-image-view.html) complete example that will help you.

Comment: all of my code already work 100%, what i need is displaying my captured image on a button.